# How can I convert the following JavaScript Promise into regular asychronous code?

Tags: javascript, promise

Hi I'm working with the following code snippet:

```
imaps.connect(config).then(function (connection) {

connection.openBox('INBOX').then(function () {

    // Fetch emails from the last 24h
    var delay = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
    var yesterday = new Date();
    yesterday.setTime(Date.now() - delay);
    yesterday = yesterday.toISOString();
    var searchCriteria = ['UNSEEN', ['SINCE', yesterday]];
    var fetchOptions = { bodies: ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)'], struct: true };

    // retrieve only the headers of the messages
    return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions);
}).then(function (messages) {

    var attachments = [];

    messages.forEach(function (message) {
        var parts = imaps.getParts(message.attributes.struct);
        attachments = attachments.concat(parts.filter(function (part) {
            return part.disposition && part.disposition.type.toUpperCase() === 'ATTACHMENT';
        }).map(function (part) {
            // retrieve the attachments only of the messages with attachments
            return connection.getPartData(message, part)
                .then(function (partData) {
                    return {
                        filename: part.disposition.params.filename,
                        data: partData
                    };
                });
        }));
    });

    return Promise.all(attachments);
}).then(function (attachments) {
    console.log(attachments);
    // =>
    //    [ { filename: 'cats.jpg', data: Buffer() },
    //      { filename: 'pay-stub.pdf', data: Buffer() } ]
});
```

I'm trying to remove Promises and turn the code into code using callbacks.

At the moment, I'm looping through all the attachments and when I print an individual attachment to the console I get:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

How can I convert the code to regular callback code such that I can access the 'filename' and 'data' attributes of the attachment?

Comment: I don't understand; it looks like you have perfectly fine, working code. Why would you want to ruin that when all you need is to access the attachment data? Aren't you already logging it?

Comment: `attachments` is an array of promises up to and before `return Promise.all(attachments);`, and an array of fulfilled values in the `.then(  function(attachments) { ` callback parameter. Where are you seeing the "`Promise { <pending> }`" console output that you weren't expecting?

Comment: "De-promisification" is not something regularly asked for and, in all probability, not required to allow you to access the 'filename' and 'data' attributes of the attachment.

Comment: If I had to make a guess, it would be that `imaps.getParts()` returns Promise but your code calls it as if it were synchronous.

Comment: The code is actually the example code from the `imap-simple` docs. I tested it myself and it works perfectly fine. Inside the last callback, I can access the final `attachments` array just fine, including saving them to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't understand why you need to go back from a promise to a callback but you can use the following code. It just a promise converter:

```
const promiseToCallback = function (promise) {
    if (!isFn(promise.then)) {
        throw new TypeError('Expected a promise');
    }

    return function (cb) {
        promise.then(function (data) {
            setImmediate(cb, null, data);
        }, function (err) {
            setImmediate(cb, err);
        });
    };
};
```

To use it

```
promiseToCallback(promise)(function(err, data) {
    ...
});
```